# Add Contact records to custom object with auto-complete search

Tags: contact, search, autocomplete

The `ContentNote` object has a list of `Contact` records on it and you are able to add multiple `Contacts` to the note at the same time using an auto-complete search feature.

[image]

[image]

I have a custom object that I would like to be able to add multiple `Contact` records to using the same auto-complete search control. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**.

What you see here is an out of the box feature and that you cannot utilize that in any of your custom flow. These components are not exposed to be reused.

If you need to have anything similar to what you see here, you will need to write custom code here.